# How to use stackNavigation with drawerNavigation in react native and use toggleDrawer() in stackNavigation component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I use react-navigation in my project. I want to use stack navigation in drawer navigation. I want to use `this.navigation.toggleDrawer()` in stack navigation screens, but not append this in stack navigation screens.

```
// drawer-navigation.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import StackNavigation from './stack-navigation';
import Screen1 from '../screens/screen1'

const RootDrawer = DrawerNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: StackNavigation,
    },
    screen1: Screen1

},{
    // set default screen
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    drawerPosition: 'right'
})

export default class DrawerNavigation extends Component {
    render() {
        return (<RootDrawer />);
    }
}

// stack-navigations

import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import Home from '../screens/home';

const RootStack = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Home,

        navigationOptions:{
            header: null
        }
    }
},{
    // set default screen
    initialRouteName: 'Home',

    // defualt style for navigation bar
    navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: '#F55656',
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
    },      
})


export default class StackNavigation extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<RootStack />);
    }
}
```

Here is my Home Component where I want to add a button in the HomeSearch Component which on click opens my drawer, but that gives me the following error:

> this.navigation.toggleDrawer() is not a function

```
// home.js (target screen)

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-smart-splash-screen';

import Header from '../components/header';
import HomeSearch from '../components/homeSearch';

class Home extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

    }


    componentDidMount(){
        // control splash screen
        SplashScreen.close({
            animationType: SplashScreen.animationType.scale,
            duration: 1500,
            delay: 1200,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <StatusBar 
                    barStyle="light-content"
                    animated={true}
                    backgroundColor='#F55656'
                />
                <Header/>
                <HomeSearch onPress={this.navigation.toggleDrawer()}/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(236, 235, 231, 0.35)',

    }
})

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

This is the wrong way exporting ReactNavigation components.

```
export default class StackNavigation extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<RootStack />);
    }
}
```

Right way.

```
export default RootStack;
```

Your `RootDrawer` would use same way.
And use `onPress=this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer`.

## Why

`createStackNavigation` and `createDrawerNavigation` wrap components and passed down props to them.

In your case, your `drawerNavigator component` inject props related in `navigation` to your stackNavigator component. But your `RootStack` cannot receive any props from drawerNavigator cause you wrapped your `RootStack` with `React Component`. That is why it is not work well. Just export your navigation componens as `RootStack` and `RootDrawer`.

> this.props.navigation: the navigation prop is passed in to every screen component (definition) in stack navigator (more about this later in "The navigation prop in depth").
>
> The navigation prop passed down to a navigator only includes state, dispatch, and addListener. This is the current state of the navigator, and an event channel to send action requests.

[Official document](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/custom-navigators.html#navigator-navigation-prop)

Comment: i use this.props.navigation.toggleDrawer() but not work .
i log this.props and in navigation object not have toggleDrawer.
i use darwer as main and for a screen in darwer use stack navigation.
i think that this.props.navigation have stack navigation objetct .